# How to sort a list by a score?

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.4

How Would I sort this list by their ***scores***?

```
class1=['Andy J:6','Nick P:7','Bob G:1','Evie F:5','James M:9','Jarrod B:10','Sean J:7']
```

So it is in the **format** when it is printed:

```
['Jarrod B:10','Andy J:6','James M:9','Nick P:7',  'Sean J:7', 'Evie F:5' , 'Bob G:1' ]
```

Their number is their score.

Comment: Your input and output are the same - why is 'Sean J' still at the end - should be between 'Evie' and 'James', surely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the built-in `sorted()` function with a simple `key` function argument — I don't think the format of the string is complicated enough to warrant using the `re` module when one call to the `split()` string method is adequate.

```
class1 = ['Andy J:6', 'Nick P:7', 'Bob G:1', 'Evie F:5', 'James M:9',
          'Jarrod B:10','Sean J:7']

print( sorted(class1, key=lambda e: int(e.split(':')[1])) )
```

Output:

```
['Bob G:1', 'Evie F:5', 'Andy J:6', 'Nick P:7', 'Sean J:7', 'James M:9',
 'Jarrod B:10']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sort()`, a custom key function, and a bit of regex to do what you want.

```
import re   # Regular expressions for string matching

def score_key( x ) :
    patt = ":(\d+)$"   # Matches the score after the colon
    return int( re.search( patt, x ).group( 1 ) )

class1 = ['Andy J:6','Nick P:7','Bob G:1','Evie F:5','James M:9','Jarrod B:10','Sean J:7']
class1.sort( key=score_key )
print( class1 )   # ['Bob G:1', 'Evie F:5', 'Andy J:6', 'Nick P:7', 'Sean J:7', 'James M:9', 'Jarrod B:10']
```

If you want to get descending order, use `class1.sort( key=score_key, reverse=True )` instead.

Comment: An `re` is a bit overkill here... `key=lambda L: int(L.rpartition(':')[2])` is more than enough